# "Error: function does not take 4 arguments" but it does

Tags: c++, function, arguments

I'm getting an error, when I try to call a function, that says "function does not take 4 arguments" but I've checked and re-checked and the function definitely does take 4 arguments, and I'm passing arguments of the right type and everything.  Here's the code in question:

Calling of function:

```
brain.minimax(board, board.getDisc('c'), board.getDisc('c'), 0);
```

Function Declaration in Brian class:

```
void minimax(Board board, int who, int currentCheck, int iter);
```

Function definition:

```
void Brain::minimax(Board board, int who, int currentCheck, int iter)
{
//code
}
```

I call minimax() at other points in the program in the same way (as far as I can tell i guess) and they don't throw any errors.

The getDisc() funciton returns an int in both the function declaration in the Board class and in its definition.  Am I missing something obvious, or is there some other reason that I might be getting this error than the obvious?  Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: We're probably going to need more code.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the exact error message, please.

Comment: Try invoking your compiler's preprocessor directly and look at the output, see what is being passed to the compiler. That might give you clue about where the offending code is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be some macro bullshittery, probably by including some dodgy C header. If I recall correctly, Windows.h #defines min and max, or something like that.

Try adding #undef minimax before the call site, or inspecting the identifier in your favourite environment to figure out what it actually is. If it shows it as a macro, you can #undef it.

Comment: @Carson Yes, but that's irrelevant. The answer suggests there is also a macro called `minimax` that is clashing with the name of your function. The answer refers to author of the macro, not author of the function.

Comment: Oh, was just making a joke about how he said I should murder whoever wrote that function